# Configurar espaço entre barras usando matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Boa tarde. Estou plotando um gráfico de barras porém não consigo ajustar o espaçamento entre as 3 barras diferentes do mesmo.

```
# plota os resultados
diameters = ['<=102', '103-152', '153-203', '203-254', '255-305', '306-356', '357-406', '407-457', 
'458-508', '509-610', '611-711', '>711']

width = 0.3
x = np.arange(len(diameters))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/1.5, count_kmeans, width=width, label='K-means', align='center')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, count_kmedoids, width=width, label='K-medoids', align='center')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width/1.5, count_hierarquico, width=width, label='Hierarquico', align='center')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Quantidade')
ax.set_title('Comparativo de diâmetros entre algoritmos')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(diameters)
ax.set_xlabel('Diâmetro nominal (mm)')
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
   """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
  for rect in rects:
      height = rect.get_height()
      ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                  xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                  xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                  textcoords="offset points",
                  ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Segue o grafico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o método `ax.bar` está plotando as barras em posições no eixo X que são menores que a largura (variável `width`) de cada barra. Por exemplo, os primeiros pontos das séries que você plota ao chamar `ax.bar` são:

```
ax.bar(x - width/1.5, ...)  -> -0.2
ax.bar(x, ...)              ->  0.0
ax.bar(x + width/1.5, ...)  ->  0.2
```

Ou seja, possuem uma distância no eixo X de `0.2` mas uma largura de barra de `0.3`, o que significa que haverá sobreposição das barras.

Sugiro reduzir o `width` e simplesmente somar/subtrair esse valor de cada série a ser plotada, sem dividi-lo por `1.5`. Por exemplo, modificando o código para:

```
width = 0.2
```

e as linhas de plotagem para:

```
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width, ... )
rects2 = ax.bar(x,... )
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width, ... )
```

as barras de um mesmo grupo ficam "coladas" umas às outras, e espaçadas em relação aos demais grupos (note que usei outros dados quaisquer porque você não forneceu as séries de valores y no seu post):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como seria se fosse dinâmico? Sem saber a quantidade antecipadamente?

Comment: @Vinithius não é algo muito intuitivo (pelo menos usando o `matplotlib`). Você provavelmente vai ter que medir uma largura ideal pras barras dividindo o intervalo de [0, 1] entre o número de categorias que você tem, e também considerar uma margem pras barras não ficarem coladas entre grupos vizinhos no eixo X. Algo como: `margin = 0.2; width = (1 - margin)/num_categorias`. E aí chamar o `ax.bar` com incrementos de `width` somados aos valores de X, por exemplo `ax.bar(x + 0 * width, ...)`, `ax.bar(x + 1 * width, ...)`, `ax.bar(x + 2 * width, ...)`, `...`.